# Signed up for AWS Elastic Beanstalk but can't access the console

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've recently signed up for AWS Elastic Beanstalk (did the phone call, etc), but when I try to access the console, it brings me to a screen that says my "Account Needs Subscription". When I click the button to sign up, the page just refreshes. It happens in my normal browser and when going through in incognito mode. Any idea why this would happen? Signed up about an hour ago; there's no waiting period or anything is there?

Thanks,
Dan

Answer (score 0):

It looks like my payment method on file had expired. Updating that fixed it...